# Internal energy calculation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

> The temperature of 1 mole of a liquid is raised by heating it with 750 joules of energy. It expands and does 200 joules of work, calculate the change in internal energy of the liquid.

I want to use the expression:
$$\Delta U = \Delta Q + \Delta W$$
so that:
$$\Delta U = 750\,\mathrm J- 200\,\mathrm J = 550\,\mathrm J$$

but it strikes me that it can't be that simple (first year college exam paper). Also, of what significance is the '1 mole' of liquid?

Comment: You proposed the right solution. Nothing to do with the amount of matter nor agregation state.

Comment: Yes. Couldn't leave it at that though, a comment has to be longer than three characters. "1 mole of liquid" is of no significance.

Comment: It is $Q$ and $W$ **not** $\Delta Q$ or $\Delta W$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. The standardized definition of the change in internal energy $U$ for a closed thermodynamic system is

$$\Delta U=Q+W$$

where $Q$ is amount of heat transferred *to the system* and $W$ is work done *on the system* (provided that no chemical reactions occur). Therefore, heat transferred to the system is assigned a positive sign in the equation
$$Q=750\ \mathrm J$$
whereas work done *by the system on the surroundings* during the expansion of the liquid is assigned a negative sign
$$W=-200\ \mathrm J$$
Thus, the change in internal energy is
$$\begin{align}
\Delta U&=Q+W\\
&=750\ \mathrm J-200\ \mathrm J\\
&=550\ \mathrm J\\
\end{align}$$

However, the question is a bit flawed since the given values are not typical for a *liquid.* By way of comparison, realistic values for *water* are shown in the following table.

$$\textbf{Water (liquid)}\\
\begin{array}{lllll}
\hline
\text{Quantity} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Initial value (0)} & \text{Final value (1)} & \text{Change}\ (\Delta) \\
\hline
\text{Amount of substance} & n & 1.00000\ \mathrm{mol} & 1.00000\ \mathrm{mol} & 0\\
\text{Volume} & V & 18.0476\ \mathrm{ml} & 18.0938\ \mathrm{ml} & 0.0462\ \mathrm{ml} \\
 & & 1.80476\times10^{-5}\ \mathrm{m^3} & 1.80938\times10^{-5}\ \mathrm{m^3} & 4.62\times10^{-8}\ \mathrm{m^3} \\
\text{Pressure} & p & 1.00000\ \mathrm{bar} & 1.00000\ \mathrm{bar} & 0 \\
 & & 100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa} & 100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa} & 0 \\
\text{Temperature} & T & 20.0000\ \mathrm{^\circ C} & 29.9560\ \mathrm{^\circ C} & 9.9560\ \mathrm{^\circ C} \\
 & & 293.1500\ \mathrm{K} & 303.1060\ \mathrm{K} & 9.9560\ \mathrm{K} \\
\text{Internal energy} & U & 1\,511.59\ \mathrm{J} & 2\,261.58\ \mathrm{J} & 749.99\ \mathrm{J} \\
\text{Enthalpy} & H & 1\,513.39\ \mathrm{J} & 2\,263.39\ \mathrm{J} & 750.00\ \mathrm{J} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

When $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of water with an initial temperature of $T_0=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ is heated with $\Delta H=Q=750\ \mathrm J$ at a constant pressure of $p=1\ \mathrm{bar}$, the resulting expansion is actually only
$$\begin{align}
\Delta V&=V_1-V_0\\
&=18.0938\ \mathrm{ml}-18.0476\ \mathrm{ml}\\
&=0.0462\ \mathrm{ml}\\
&=4.62\times10^{-8}\ \mathrm{m^3}
\end{align}$$

The corresponding pressure-volume work is
$$\begin{align}
W&=p\Delta V\\
&=100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa}\times4.62\times10^{-8}\ \mathrm{m^3}\\
&=0.00462\ \mathrm J
\end{align}$$
which is clearly below the value given in the question $(W=200\ \mathrm J)$.

The values given in the question are appropriate for a *gas.* For example, realistic values for *nitrogen* are shown in the following table.

$$\textbf{Nitrogen (gas)}\\
\begin{array}{lllll}
\hline
\text{Quantity} & \text{Symbol} & \text{Initial value (0)} & \text{Final value (1)} & \text{Change}\ (\Delta) \\
\hline
\text{Amount of substance} & n & 1.00000\ \mathrm{mol} & 1.00000\ \mathrm{mol} & 0\\
\text{Volume} & V & 24.3681\ \mathrm{l} & 26.5104\ \mathrm{l} & 2.1423\ \mathrm{l} \\
 & & 0.0243681\ \mathrm{m^3} & 0.0265104\ \mathrm{m^3} & 0.0021423\ \mathrm{m^3} \\
\text{Pressure} & p & 1.00000\ \mathrm{bar} & 1.00000\ \mathrm{bar} & 0 \\
 & & 100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa} & 100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa} & 0 \\
\text{Temperature} & T & 20.0000\ \mathrm{^\circ C} & 45.7088\ \mathrm{^\circ C} & 25.7088\ \mathrm{^\circ C} \\
 & & 293.1500\ \mathrm{K} & 318.8588\ \mathrm{K} & 25.7088\ \mathrm{K} \\
\text{Internal energy} & U & 6\,081.06\ \mathrm{J} & 6\,616.83\ \mathrm{J} & 535.77\ \mathrm{J} \\
\text{Enthalpy} & H & 8\,517.87\ \mathrm{J} & 9\,267.87\ \mathrm{J} & 750.00\ \mathrm{J} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

When $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of nitrogen with an initial temperature of $T_0=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ is heated with $\Delta H=Q=750\ \mathrm J$ at a constant pressure of $p=1\ \mathrm{bar}$, the resulting pressure-volume work is

$$\begin{align}
W&=p\Delta V\\
&=100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa}\times0.0021423\ \mathrm{m^3}\\
&=214.23\ \mathrm{J}
\end{align}$$
The corresponding enthalpy balance
$$\begin{align}
\Delta H&=\Delta U+W\\
750.00\ \mathrm{J}&=535.77\ \mathrm{J}+214.23\ \mathrm{J}
\end{align}$$
is quite similar to the values of the question $(\Delta H=Q=750\ \mathrm J,$ $\Delta U=550\ \mathrm J,$ and $W=200\ \mathrm{J}).$